# Is there a shortcut to move the cursor as shown in the following figure?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using a notebook without a mouse.

After typing `prop` and pressing `tab`, Visual Studio will automatically give me a property template. Pressing `tab` will move the cursor between `type` and `propertyname` placeholders.

I want to move the cursor to a new line after completing the property template.

Is there a shortcut to do so?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use ENTER?

Comment: @John: it will move the opening curly brace down :D

Comment: @Hans: Put your comment as an answer. It will be green-checked. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Press the Enter key twice.

I tried to post this answer 3 times before I left the comment.  It wouldn't let me, too short.  That's why I'm typing this otherwise useless verbiage.

Answer (score 5):

It's not specific to snippets, but you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to start a new line below where the cursor currently is.

To insert a new line *above* where the cursor currently is, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Both of these work anywhere in the editor.  Both of these are handy because they work no matter where you are horizontally on your current line.

Comment: Your solution works well but it is not simpler than Hans' solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Administrator: happy to help.  I like Hans' answer as well, I learned something, too :)

Comment: These work in **Atmel Studio 6.1**, but accepted answer does not.

Answer (score 1):

Update: [**Productivity PowerTools** for VS2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) (Woot! [2012 too](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd)) provides the keyboard shortcut `Tools.AddEndTokenAtEnd`.  (Thanks Ben.)

For some reason, magically, my VS2010 does this with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> (which I prefer from my experience with TextMate.)  Looking at my keyboard bindings (Tools > Customize > Keyboard) I see that this shortcut is assigned to the command `Tools.AddEndTokenAtTheEnd`.  So if that command appears in your list of commands, assigning a keyboard shortcut to it should work.  I have Productivity Power Tools, PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2010, and ReSharper installed.  But I can't find any setting from the first two that would be responsible, and, in my experience, all of ReSharper's commands contain its name, so I don't think it added the command.  Ooo, and I just discovered that the reason it is named that is because the command also ensures there's a semicolon at the end of the initial line before moving the cursor down; just like the useful keyboard shortcut in Textmate.

I'm interested, but baffled by the 2x-<kbd>Enter</kbd> solution.  When I press enter twice I get two line breaks followed by whatever code was after the cursor on the first line.  Can anyone explain how that shortcut/key-combination works?  Is it time-sensitive so that the two enters must be pressed in rapid succession?  What if the user wants to quickly insert some lines above some code and hits <kbd>Return</kbd> multiple times!?

Comment: I have Power Tools and ReSharper, and this command is not in the list for me. Installing PowerCommands now...

Comment: ...and I still didn't have that command; then I discovered Power Tools was disabled. It seems to be responsible for this.

Comment: "... baffled by the 2x-`Enter` solution". This works for me when in snippet-customise mode (i.e. editing the snippet fields after insertion), as in the question. A single `Enter` exits this mode with the cursor at the end of the inserted snippet. I don't have any tools installed which alter the available key commands (I don't think!). For the reasons you mention, it can't really work during normal editing.