# Move Line Up/Down shortcut in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

In VS2010 I had a shortcut set up <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> to move lines of code up or down, just like I used to have in Eclipse in my Java days.

Now since Power Tools and macros (which is how I set up this shortcut in VS2010) are not available in VS2012, how do I get this to work?

I've seen somebody mentioned that Resharper can do this, but for the love of fire and water, I can't find the command names in the list of commands that can do that.
I have tried ReSharper_MoveUp/MoveDown and that does not move lines up/down:

[image: Move_Up command did not do the trick]

This moves blocks of text up and down. I just want line-by-line up or down, no fancy logic there.
Before

[image: What I have]

After <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (when cursor is on WriteLine line)  I would like to see this:

[image: Line moved one up, inside the bracket, indented]

I have seen these threads: [What's the equivalent for eclipse's ALT+UP/DOWN (move line) in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526715/whats-the-equivalent-for-eclipses-altup-down-move-line-in-visual-studio), [Visual Studio: hotkeys to move line up/down and move through recent changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313462/visual-studio-hotkeys-to-move-line-up-down-and-move-through-recent-changes), but none of the suggested solutions work in VS2012.

Any other ideas?

**UPD 7 Nov 2012:** . Extensions are catching up with Visual Studio 2012. Now I know at least 3 extensions that provide this functionality:

- [MoveLine Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3ee08dc-a28f-4aec-9efa-69215ab5ee52). Link provided by [Carl G](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696202/809357)
- [Move Line Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/814eb3c4-7d5e-4217-9711-e20117b20649) with modifications to 2010 version. By [gius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12530141/809357)
- [Productivity Power Tools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd). Have not actually tried this, but [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/11/07/productivity-power-tools-2012.aspx) states it does the line move up/down

**UPD 15 Nov 2012:** Just stumbled across another extension that claims it does what is required here. Have not tried it though: [LineMan Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/92ef7620-d7f6-493f-825a-ba52d07d56c2?SRC=VSIDE)

**UPD 10 May 2015** Just installed VS2015 RC and this is built-in already:
[image: MoveLineUp/Down]

Comment: FYI [PowerTools 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) is out and has this now.

Comment: This also applies for atmel Studio 7 for moving lines up and down.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Update: huzzah, [Productivity PowerTools VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd) is now available and offers this functionality (along with another personal favorite, [`Tools.AddEndTokenAtTheEnd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12766988/39396).)

[MoveLine Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b3ee08dc-a28f-4aec-9efa-69215ab5ee52) (compatible with VS 2012; I had to manually restart my VS in order to see the commands in VS's keyboard shortcut tool.)

Comment: When you setup a keyboard shortcut, make a scope to "Text Editor".

Comment: They key to success here is that your shortcut should scope to Text Editor AND you need to REMOVE (REMOVE) existing keyboard shortcuts already assigned.  If you have resharper you need to remove 'Resharper.Resharper.GoToNextMethod' and '..GoToPrevMethod' (note there may be two shortcuts (XAML and Text Editor) that need to be removed.

Comment: @Carl G - Is there any way to move horizontally word by short cut? like Alt + Up  or Alt + Down ?

Answer (score 66):

Since VS 2013, the shortcut comes with built-in keybinds:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd>

These move the selected line(s) up and down. If a line isn't selected, but the text entry cursor is on the line, that also works without having to select the line.

If you wish to rebind it in *Tools* > *Options* > *Environment* > *Keyboard*, the identifier keys are `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp` and `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown`. You may need to remove your new combination from other existing keys first.

Comment: The question was about 2012.

Comment: @trailmax I'm aware, and that already got its answers but I'm posting this so that people using 2013 can be aware that this already exists so they don't go searching farther like I had to.

Comment: @RayL Maybe you rebound those keys to something else?

Comment: @Keavon.  What's the offical VS command called? I'm having trouble finding it in the keyboard mapping tool.

Comment: @RayL `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp` and `Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown`. Please report back if those work for you.

Comment: @keavon, That works but For some reason I'm not able to assign "Atl + up arrow" to that command....maybe has something to do with resharper or powertools being installed. I think that's what initially screwed me up. Odd. "ctrl+alt+UP Arrow" works great though! Thanks.

Comment: @RayL Maybe one of your plugins is taking over the keyboard shortcut. When you enter the shortcut it shows the ones already occupying it. Try removing those.

Comment: @Ray, I can verify that Resharper hijacks the `alt+arrow` shortcuts.

Answer (score 10):

Install ReSharper.

Open Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard (as shown in a picture)

1. Find "ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveUp"
2. In "Use new shortcut in:" choose: "Text Editor"
3. Click in "Press shortcut keys:" and press your shortcut (for example Alt+ArrowUp)
4. Press "Assign" button
   Same with with "ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveDown"

P.S. Works fine for single lines and multiple selected lines, but removes selection after moved 1 line. Hope there are way to move multiple lines multiple times in one selection.

Comment: nah, resharper is trying to be too helpful and pushes it too much this time. It moves the block of code with current line. And all I want is to simply move one line up or down, not a related block.

Comment: For me "ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveUp" and "ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveDown" commands moves only one current line if no selection, even inside block. Not sure why you have it another way. I use ReSharper 7.0.97.60 and VS 2012 RTM from MSDN.

Comment: An example of where this does not work is when a `using` statement appears at the top of a file, and the user wants to move the statement down several lines so as to be within the `namespace` definition.  Using R#'s MoveDown command works correctly for a few iterations, until the `using` statement appears just under the `namespace` line.  Now the next iteration will attempt to move the namespace below its current block.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Resharper, then you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> to move the current line up. or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> to move one line down.

This works in VS 2012 Premium with Visual Studio keyboard scheme in Resharper 7 (7.0.97.60 to 
be precise).

Edit: This is mapped to 'ReSharper.ReSharper_MoveUp'/'MoveDown' commands.

Comment: That does not work for me for some reason. I've got exactly the same resharper and map the same commands. And whenever I try to move the lines up/down, they are jumping in a crazy way: sometimes up into another method, sometimes down below next block. But not what I want -(

Comment: Yups - I saw that, albeit a bit too late. Did you tried resetting your keyboard mapping? Might be the shortcuts are mapped to a different command? Your screen shot says it's mapped for XAML, can you see if it's mapped for Text as well?

Comment: Yep, did check for Text Editor. In fact, I have just reinstalled VS2012 and Resharper and it has default mapping. Your shortcuts do work, but it does not move one line up or down - moves a block up or down -(

Comment: It moves the complete code block if the cursor is placed on line beginning / ending code block. Did you tried selecting the entire line and then trying the shortcut?

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2017(atleast) I have below

[image]

Comment: Its in VS2019 where you show, but the keys were not mapped (at least in my installation). Had to map the keys manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Move Line Command](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/814eb3c4-7d5e-4217-9711-e20117b20649) extension.

Just follow formula349's comment:

> I was able to get this working with 2012 as-is.
>
> Rename the package to .zip and unzip all files into a folder. Edit the extension.vsixmanifest file and look for the SupportedProducts XML node. Change the Version="10.0" to Version="11.0".
>
> Re-zip the folder contents and rename back to .vsix. Works great!

Comment: There's an [extension compatible with 2012 out of the box](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12696202/39396).

Comment: Sorry gius. I have missed your answer - was away on holidays and did not get a notification for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

While a lot of people seem to be recommending misc. Visual Studio Extensions and Resharper, I would like to point out there is a ***native*** hotkey that accomplishes this goal. I came to this question trying to find the answer, as my Resharper replaced my default hotkeys with their MoveUp and MoveDown versions.

And while Resharper's hotkeys do move things up and down, they are *not* what the original poster are looking for, and they are not what I wanted. These hotkeys move methods and blocks of code, *not* individual lines.

Visual studio has two hotkey commands to move your selected lines upwards or downwards.
These hotkeys are:

- Edit.MoveSelectedLinesDown
- Edit.MoveSelectedLinesUp

I am using Visual Studio 2013 however, so I am unaware if these exist in an older version. If 2012 does not have these hotkeys then perhaps an extension is the only solution.

Either way, I had an issue locating the exact hotkey within visual studio's list and it took me a good while to find these, so I hope that my solution manages to help someone else in a similar situation to my own.

Comment: Aye, these did not exist in VS2012. And second answer states that VS2013 has these.

Comment: Preach!  Resharper is frowned upon in my current company, so I'm trying to get around it... after uninstally Resharper all my shortcuts are busted :(

Answer (score 1):

**<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> does the **cut** (same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) operation on the current line on which cursor is positioned.

Then you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it at any place you like.

Good thing is that you don't need to select the *complete current line*, just the cursor needs to be positioned on the line.

One downside to using this shortcut is that you won't be able to see the line moving ( up or down ) *lively* in front of your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper's move up and move down shortcuts are smart - instead of just moving the current line (which can easily result in broken code), it will move the current statement up and down in the list of statements that make up the method body. This is much more powerful than just moving a single line of code.

But this doesn't help you get your statement inside the `if` block. Here you need to do one of two things.

Firstly, move the statement *above* the `if` block, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to push it down in scope. The statement will now be inside the `if` block, and you can use up and down to move it around in there. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> to pull it up in scope, outside of the `if` block.

Alternatively, you can put the text caret on the outside of the closing brace of the `if` block and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to move the brace down, stepping over following statements, including them inside the `if` block.

These keys can do a lot more than just move a single statement. If you put the text caret on a method or class declaration, <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> will move the entire method or class declaration up and down. If you put the text caret in the parameter list of a method, <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> will rearrange individual parameters (and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> can invoke the Change Signature refactoring).

More details in the [help pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Coding_Assistance__Moving_Code_Elements.html).

Comment: Shortcuts trying to be "smart" is the problem with R#. A lot of times I just need to move a line up or down, nothing to do with the scope or braces.

Comment: Well, if you're not interested in understanding how the commands you were asking about work, then I can't help. ReShaprer isn't "trying" to be smart, it understands the structure of your code and is helping you rearrange it. Use the editor's own commands for editing plain text. This isn't ReSharper's "problem" - it's giving you tooling, you can either learn it and use it, or use something else.